# Getting values from a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
id, values
1, ['This is a house, it is black.', 'It is beautiful', 'It costs 10.000']
2, ['I have a dog', 'His name is ball', 'I like him']
```

How can I get the values of the second column in the following way?

`array[0] = "This is a house, it is black."`

`array[1] = "It is beautiful"`

In the following code, I can get the values.

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(',').withFirstRecordAsHeader();
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, format);
List<CSVRecord> records  = parser.getRecords();
```

However, I get `array[0] = ['This is a house, it is black.', 'It is beautiful', 'It costs 10.000']`

Comment: Where is `array` defined in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you get a 2 dimensional array where the first dimension represents the rows and the second dimension the columns.

Simply try `array[0][0]` to get the first value of the first row of your data. Or `records.get(0).get(0)` given your code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.